# Confusion about infinitely many bounded prime gaps?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-gaps

I was working at something and I had this idea: Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x > 0$. Let $p_n$ denote the $n$'th prime number. Then by mean value theorem $$ f(p_{n+1}) - f(p_n) = f'(c_n) (p_{n+1} - p_n)$$ where $c_n \in (p_n,p_{n+1})$. Hence $$ \frac{1}{p_{n+1}} = -\frac{1}{c_n^2} (p_{n+1} - p_n) + \frac{1}{p_n}$$ Suppose that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ $p_{n+1} - p_n > D$ where $D$ is a positive constant. Then $-\frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{c_n^2} < -\frac{D}{p_{n+1}^2}$ hence $$ \frac{1}{p_{n+1}} < -D\sum_{i=N+1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{p_i^2} + \frac{1}{p_N} = -D \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{p_i^2} + D\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p_i^2} + \frac{1}{p_N}$$ Now $Z_p(2,n+1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{p_i^2} $ is bounded (converges to prime zeta function of 2). Therefore

$$ \frac{1}{p_{n+1}} < -D \cdot Z_p(2,n+1) + D\cdot C_2 + \frac{1}{p_N}$$ where $C_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p_i^2}$. Obviously $C_2 < Z_p(2,n+1)$. We take $D$ such that $D \cdot \left( C_2 - Z_p(2,n+1)\right) + \frac{1}{p_N} < 0$ that is $$ D > \frac{1}{p_N \cdot \left( Z_p(2,n+1) - C_2\right)} > 0$$ to obtain a contradiction ! Therefore there are infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{n_k+1} - p_{n_k} < D$ ?!

As mentioned in the comments the question is whether $\frac{1}{p_N \cdot \left( Z_p(2,n+1) - C_2\right)}$ is bounded above for $N > 0$ ?

Edit:

The answer is NO!

Comment: I don't understand how the step $$\frac{1}{p_{n + 1}} < -D \sum_{i = N + 1}^{n + 1} \frac{1}{p_i^2} + \frac{1}{p_N}$$ is justified. From $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ $$-\frac{p_{n + 1} - p_n}{c_n^2} < -\frac{D}{p_{n + 1}^2}$$I can only conclude $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ $$\frac{1}{p_{n + 1}} < -\frac{D}{p_{n + 1}^2} + \frac{1}{p_n}$$

Comment: By repeating the thing from $p_n$ all the way down to $p_N$ :)

Comment: What do you think sir? Have I done a mistake ? A faulty logic ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can take $D > \dots$ at the end. Isn't $D$ already fixed in the beginning?

Comment: I am saying how it should have been fixed at the beginning  to obtain a contradiction ... right?

Comment: According to this proof, you've essentially made $D$ arbitrary, and this is obviously impossible. If $D < \epsilon < 1$, you're showing that $p_{n+1} - p_n < \epsilon < 1$ which is obviously false. I can't find where the mistake is, but the conclusion is false.

Comment: Well, $D$ is not arbitrary small ... it has to be greater then $\frac{1}{p_N\cdot RZ_p(2,N)}$ where $RZ_p(2,N)$ is the rest of the convergent series $Z_p(2)$. $RZ_p(2,N)$ is a small number (converges to zeros for $N \to \infty$) therefore multiplied by $p_N$ it might be smaller then one hence $D > $ something ... right?

Comment: Well then, what if $\frac{1}{p_N RZ_p(2,N)} \not \to 0$ as $N\to\infty$ (which it is true), namely $\frac{1}{p_N RZ_p(2,N)} > M$ for some $M$, then all this says is the the prime gaps can be less then $M$. Actually we should be able to say something stronger: $\frac{1}{p_N RZ_p(2,N)} \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$, and all you are left with is $p_{n+1} - p_n < \infty$.

Comment: Mind you, I haven't looked too carefully at these things, but that seems to be the case. That is if I've understood what you've said. It's a little hard to read your proof, because it's rather blunt.

Comment: I think the problem is that $p_n < c_n < p_{n + 1}$ doesn't give $\frac{1}{c_n^2} < \frac{1}{p_{n + 1}^2}$.

Comment: The serious problem is whether $\frac{1}{p_N \cdot \left( Z_p(2,n+1) - C_2\right)}$ is bounded or not, and I am afraid is not! $\frac{1}{c_n^2} > \frac{1}{p_{n+1}^2}$ hence $-\frac{1}{c_n^2} < -\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^2}$

Comment: @CMarius I think since $p_{n + 1} - p_n > D \implies -(p_{n + 1} - p_n) < -D$, the minus sign "has already been used".

Comment: @CMarius Sorry, maybe I confuse you. I mean there is a problem with $-\frac{p_{n + 1} - p_n}{c_n^2} < -\frac{D}{p_{n + 1}^2}$. Also, the quantity you mentioned above is bounded by $$\frac{1}{p_N (Z_p(2, N + 1) - C_2)}$$

Comment: $-\frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{c_n^2} < \frac{- (p_{n+1} - p_n)}{p_{n+1}^2}$ right? And now because $p_{n+1} - p_n \geq D$ follows $-(p_{n+1} - p_n) < -D$ hence $-\frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{c_n^2} < \frac{- (p_{n+1} - p_n)}{p_{n+1}^2} < \frac{-D}{p_{n+1}^2}$

Comment: See also the discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271597/the-existence-of-a-function-with-application-in-finding-bounded-gaps-between-pri

Answer (score 0):

You conclude at some point:

> Therefore $$\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}<−D\cdot Z_p(2,n+1)+D\cdot C_2+\frac{1}{p_N}$$

which basically is the same as;
$$\color{red}{0<}\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}<\color{red}{D\cdot \left(C_2- Z_p(2,n+1)\right)+\frac{1}{p_N}}$$

and the next thing you do is:

> We take $D$ such that $D\cdot \left(C_2−Z_p(2,n+1)\right)+\frac{1}{p_N}\color{red}{<0}$ ...

Do you see the problem?

Comment: Sir I do not see the problem ... I want to produce a contradiction ... but unfortunately it seems I can not choose $D$ independently of $N$ :(

Comment: It is a problem, you are asking for something to be $<0$ whether previously you showed the very same something being $>0$ .

Comment: That was supposed to be the contradiction ... in the sense that if $\frac{1}{p_N(Z_p(2,n+1) - C_2)} < M$ then I say take $D > M$ and all is perfect, but I am afraid that quotient is not bounded ...

Comment: Even if you assume that, you will obtain $M\cdot \left(C_2−Z_p(2,n+1)\right)+\frac{1}{p_N}\color{red}{<0 <} D\cdot \left(C_2- Z_p(2,n+1)\right)+\frac{1}{p_N}$ leading to $M > D$ ... it's flowed in any case.

Comment: I am saying that if $\frac{1}{p_N ... } < M$ for all $N > 0 $ then the proof starts like this "Suppose $p_{n+1} - p_n > D$ " for $n > N$ and $D > M$ etc ... at the end there will be the contradiction :)